# Advanced properties not appearing on files

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to change some filed to "copy always" in order for my program to work, but when I click on the text files to change this property, I cannot see the advanced tab, any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is the file included in the project?  Right click on the file in Solution Explorer and see if "Include in Project" is available.  If the file is not part of the project, its icon will appear faded in Solution Explorer.

Answer (score -2):

Even i faced the same issue. This is because - that file is not under the project directory. place that file inside the C# executable folder path and try.
It worked for me.